# ASP.NET label in HTML accessDataSource

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I need to replace the ? with lblDates.Text,how is that possible?? lblDates is a label to which I saved a date(string) from calendar,so I need this so I can fill the gridview

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
     DataFile="~/App_data/Baza1.accdb" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Spol], [Prezime], [Vrijeme], [Stol] FROM [rezervacije] WHERE ([Datum] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblDates" Name="Datum" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `ControlParameter` that retrieves `lblDates.Text` has `Name="Datum"`, replace `?` in `SelectCommand` with `@Datum`:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_data/Baza1.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Spol], [Prezime], [Vrijeme], [Stol] FROM [rezervacije] WHERE ([Datum] = @Datum)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblDates" Name="Datum" PropertyName="Text" 
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

For more information, see [Using Parameters with Data Source Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).